# Rails: how to format and organize routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a rails newbie (building my first app) and right now my routes.rb is quite a mess. I was wondering what is the best way to organize/format all the content so it is easy to see what is going on and avoid silly routing errors.

Any general tips or simplified examples would be appreciated.

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :posts

get 'users/index'

#devise_for :admins

namespace :super_admin do #superadmin stuff
resources :dashboard, only: [:index]
end

devise_for :super_admins, path: "super_admin", controllers: { registrations: "registrations", sessions: "super_admin/sessions" } #lets super admin sign in 



get 'welcome/index'
root to: "welcome#index"

match '/teachers',   to: 'teachers#index',   via: 'get'

#route to delete users
match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user
match '/users/:id',     to: 'users#show',       via: 'get'



#routes for registration
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
devise_for :teachers, controllers: { registrations: "teacher/registrations" }





get 'users/:id/posts' => 'users#posts', :as => :user_posts
match '/users',   to: 'users#index',   via: 'get'

match '/about',   to: 'about#index',   via: 'get'


match '/teachers/:id',     to: 'teachers#show',       via: 'get'
match '/teachers/list',   to: 'teachers#list',   via: 'get'

get 'super_admin/dashboard/new_user', :as => :super_admin_new_user 

resources :users, :only =>[:show]
```

Comment: It looks pretty good to me except that you are repeating the welcome index route twice. If you want that to be your root route just use `root "welcome#index"` and delete the get request above it.

Comment: I would recommend asking this question is StackOverflow chat if you have enough rep. Furthermore I would suggest removing the excessive spacing. I use no more than 1 blank space between sections of code.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it's simply part of rails that this file gets messy over time. Our app has hundreds of entries for various items that have been added over the years, so I know from experience it's good to think of from the beginning.

The **number one thing you can do** to keep the file organized is to add lots of comments, with some kind of consistency that helps you understand how they match your app, for example:

```
# ADMIN FUNCTIONALITY
# -- Allows super admin access and functionality
# your admin stuff here
```

And then keep your routes for certain functionality in the same section. In your example, you have a "teachers" route near the top, and then some more near the bottom. Keep those grouped together and commented and it'll be easier to manage in the long run.